# Organizing interconnected objects

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, simulation

This is a generic question, I don't know if it belongs to Programming or StackOverflow.

I'm writing a litte simulation. Without going very deep into its details, consider that many kind of identities are involved. They correspond to Object since I'm using a OOP language.

- There are **Guys** that inhabit the world simulated
- There are **Maps**
- A map has many **Lots**, that are pieces of land with some characteristics
- There are **Tribes** (guys belong to tribes)
- There is a generic class called **Position** to locate the elements
- There are **Bots** in control of tribes that move guys around
- There is a **World** that represents the world simulated

and so on.

If the simulated world was laid down as a database, the objects would be tables with lots of references, but in memory I have to use a different strategy. So, for example, a Tribe has an array of Guys as a property, The world has a, array of Bots, of Tribes, of Maps. A Map has a Dictionary whose key is a Position and whose value is a Lot. A Guy has a Position that is where he stands.

The way I lay down such connections is pretty much arbitrary. For example, I could have an array of Guys in the World, or an Array of guys *per Lot* (the guys standing on a piece of land), or an array of Guys *per Bot* (with the Guys controlled by the bot).

Doing so, I also have to pass around a lot of objects. For example, a Bot must have informations about the Map and opponent Guys to decide how to move its Guys.

As said, in a database I'd have a Guys table connected to the Lots table (indicating its position), to the Tribe table (indicating which Tribe it belongs to) and so it would also be easy to query "All the guys in Position [1, 5]". "All the Guys of Tribe 123". "All the Guys controlled by Bot B standing on the Lot b34 not belonging to the Tribe 456" and so on.

I've worked with APIs where to get the simplest information you had to make an instance of the CustomerContextCollection and pass it to CustomerQueryFactory to get back a CustomerInPlaceQuery to... When people criticize OOP and cite verbose abstractions that soon smell ridiculous, that's what I mean. I want to avoid such things and having to relay on deep abstractions and (anti pattern) abstract contexts.

The question is: what is the preferred, clean way to manage entities and collections of entities that are deeply linked in multiple ways?

Comment: What language are you Using? C++? Java? C#? In each language you have to do it a little bit different

Comment: I didn't mention any language because I'd rather have this discussion language agnostic. By the way, I'm using Ruby, but I had the very same thoughts working with Clojure, C#, Java and basically every language I've written some toy simulation in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "clean". In my case, I define clean as: I can implement desired behavior in an obvious, efficient manner.

Building OOP software is not a data modeling exercise. I'd suggest stepping back a little. What does each one of those objects actually *do*? What methods are you going to implement?

Just because "guys are in a lot" doesn't mean that the lot object needs a collection of guys; it only needs one if there are operations on a lot that affect all the guys in it. And even then, it doesn't necessarily need a collection of guys - *it needs a way to get the guys in the lot*. This may be an internally stored collection, but it could also be a simple method that calls back into the world to find guys matching a criteria. The implementation of that lookup should be transparent to anyone.

From the tenor of your questions, it seems like you're thinking of this from a "how do I generate reports" perspective. Step back and think of the behaviors you're trying to implement first.

Another thing I find extremely valuable is to differentiate between Entities and Values. Entities are objects where identity matters - you may have two guys, both named "Chris", but they are two different objects and remain distinct despite having the same "key". Values, on the other hand, act like ints. From your above list, Position sounds a lot like a value - Position(0,0) is Position(0,0) regardless of which chunk of memory (identity) those bits are stored in. The distinction has a bit effect on how you compare and store values vs. entities. For example, your Guy objects (entities) would store their Position as a simple member variable.

I've found a great reference for how to think about such things is Eric Evan's "Domain Driven Design" book. He's focused on business systems, but the discussions are very valuable for how you think about building OO systems in general I've found.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that *no* 'true' answer exists to your core question -- a *best* way to manage collections of entities that are linked in multiple ways. It really **depends on the kind of application** (simulation) - here are some thoughts:

**Is execution time important?**

If this is the case, there is really no way around *analyzing* in which way your simulator will iterate over (query) the objects from the pool: sketch out the basic simulation loop and check what kind of events will require to iterate over what kind of model entities (I assume you are developing a discrete-event simulation?). Then you should organize the data structures in a way that optimizes the most frequent/time-consuming events (as opposed to "laying down the connections arbitrarily"). Additionally, you may want to **use special data structures** (such as [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree)) to organize entities with properties that you need to query often (e.g., position data). For some typical problems, e.g. collision detection, there is also a whole lot of approaches to solve them efficiently (so look for suitable libraries/frameworks, e.g. for [multi-agent simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_simulation)).

**How flexible do you want to make it?**

If you really want to make it super-flexible and *really* don't want to decide on the hierarchy of the model entities, why not just use an [**in-memory database**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database)? As you already said, databases are easily applicable to your problem (and you can easily save the model state, which may also be useful).

**How clean is clean enough?**

If you want to be absolutely sure that the rest of your simulator is not affected by the design choices you make in regards of your model representation, **hide it behind an interface** (say, `ModelWorld`), which defines methods for all the types of queries your simulator may invoke (this is orthogonal to the second point and may help with the first point, i.e. figuring out what kind of access pattern your simulator exhibits). This allows you to **change implementations** easily, without affecting any other parts of the simulator code.